# How _xabort(status) in HTM works?

Tags: c++, gcc, intrinsics, transactional-memory, intel-tsx

I used `_xabort(status)` function in my code, in order to release the buffer in cache. I check the transaction whether it's successful, if the transaction success, I use `_xend()`, otherwise I use `_xabort(status)`. Can I use the `_xabort(status)` in this situation?

```
unsigned status = 0;
while(true)
{
    status = _xbegin();
    if(status == _XBEGIN_STARTED)
    {
         //Transaction code
         bool success = transaction_func();
         if(success)
         {
             _xend();
             break;
         }
         else
         {
             _xabort(0Xff);
             continue;
         }
    }
}
```

Can I use the `_xabort(status)` like this? it's a single thread situation, I check the `transaction_func()` by myself, and call `_xabort(status)`.
I think it's a issue about usage of `_xabort(status)`, I don't know whether it can remain in `(status == _XBEGIN_STARTED)` area. In my opinion, if the status equals `_XBEGIN_STARTED`, it will not abort the transaction, so this code is not right?

If `transction_func()` return false, `printf` the `status` in this code, why the status value is '0xff000001'?

Comment: you may want to distinguish if you want to retry the current transaction (_XABORT_RETRY) or completely abort it (_XABORT_EXPLICIT).

Comment: Hi, thanks, if I don't distinguish, you mean `_xabort(status)` don't know how abort the transaction, so nothing will be done?

Comment: I not sure what will happen if you don't set the status of the _xabort, not clear on the spec, or I haven't found one that explains such scenarios.

Comment: Hi, thanks, Actually I set the status as 0xff(-1), you mean I must set the status as _XABORT_RETRY or _XABORT_EXPLICIT?

Comment: In my understanding, yes.

Comment: yes, I see, If we implement the multi-threads code, do we have to call `_xabort(status)`, I think sometimes it's no need to invoke the function.